# get the hightest value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I would like to get the hightest value of array (only the 'y'), how can I do that?

I'm getting only the value of array setting into`[]` like values[0]

```js
data = [
    {
      values: [
        { x:'2017-01', y: 1.2 },
        { x:'2017-02', y: 1.3 },
        { x:'2017-03', y: 1.5 },
        { x:'2017-04', y: 1.6 },
        { x:'2017-05', y: 1.8 },
        { x:'2017-06', y: 1.9 },
        { x:'2017-07', y: 1.5 },
        { x:'2017-08', y: 1.7 },
        { x:'2017-09', y: 1.5 },
        { x:'2017-10', y: 0 }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(Math.max(d.values[0].y));
  });
```

Comment: There's only a single member in `data` array.

Comment: You're iterating through the `data` array when you want to iterate through the `values` (or rather `data[0].values`) array.

Comment: Look up how Math.max works...need at least 2 items to compare

Comment: Try using `data[0].values` to get the actual array then use the answer from the other question to get the max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `values` are a property of the 1st object (index 0) of the array - `data[0].values`. Get all `y` values using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) [Math#max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to get the maximum:

```js
var data = [{"values":[{"x":"2017-01","y":1.2},{"x":"2017-02","y":1.3},{"x":"2017-03","y":1.5},{"x":"2017-04","y":1.6},{"x":"2017-05","y":1.8},{"x":"2017-06","y":1.9},{"x":"2017-07","y":1.5},{"x":"2017-08","y":1.7},{"x":"2017-09","y":1.5},{"x":"2017-10","y":0}]}];
  
var result = Math.max.apply(null, data[0].values.map(function(o) {
  return o.y;
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you want to get the object with maximum value `y` from `data[0].values`, since `data` itself is an array with only one element.

If you wanted to only get the max value of `y` (1.9), you could use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Getting_the_maximum_element_of_an_array), but if you want to get the whole object that has maximum `y`, you would need to iterate through the array again to find the object that has `y == 1.9`.

Instead you can do both at once using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which iterates through the array calling the callback on each element similarly to [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), except the value you return from the callback on each iteration is passed as an argument to the next iteration

```js
data = [
    {
      values: [
        { x:'2017-01', y: 1.2 },
        { x:'2017-02', y: 1.3 },
        { x:'2017-03', y: 1.5 },
        { x:'2017-04', y: 1.6 },
        { x:'2017-05', y: 1.8 },
        { x:'2017-06', y: 1.9 },
        { x:'2017-07', y: 1.5 },
        { x:'2017-08', y: 1.7 },
        { x:'2017-09', y: 1.5 },
        { x:'2017-10', y: 0 }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
var max = data[0].values.reduce( function( maxSoFar, current ) {
    // If current.y is larger than maxSoFar.y, return current
    // so that it becomes maxSoFar for the next iteration
    return current.y > maxSoFar.y ? current : maxSoFar;
});

console.log( max );
```